# laravel 5.1 on windows azure web application

Tags: php, laravel, azure, iis, web-config

I want to deploy a `laravel` app on my `azure` web application

but that return this `error`

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I know my `web.config` was setting error ..

I search some resource also can't resolve my question ...

http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2015/06/26/configuring-and-hosting-laravel-5-x-applications-on-windows-azure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Azure Web site’s root directory is `site\wwwroot`, when we are deploying projects from Github to Azure Web Apps, Azure will automatically move the project to the root path `site\wwwroot`. So it is not necessary to change the root directory.

On my side, I cloned your project, deployed it on Azure by git, and browsed the URL `<site_name>. azurewebsites.net/public` to check project. I got the error message about the project couldn’t find the file `vendor/autoload.php`, so it looks like the project was lack of dependence.

I installed composer as the article you provided told in KUDU Console site. The URL should be `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/` (first installed composer, we need to restart the console site).

Then click “**Debug console**”=>”**CMD**” at the header navigation of the console site to enter in command line tool, change directory to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and run `composer install`, after finishing installation, we browse `<site_name>.azurewebsites.net/public` again, and it works well.

To set the URL rewrite to remove the “`public`”, we can simply modify “`site\wwwroot`” to “`site\wwwroot\public`” at **virtual applications and directories** section in Azure portal.

In addition you may want PHP project to show detailed errors during testing. By default, “`display_errors`” is off, we can simply create a file named “`.user.ini`” in the root directory and wirte “`display_errors = on`” in this file. Please read [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations) for more information.